# cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Vector3' to 'UnityEngine.Quaternion'

Tags: unity-game-engine

i got this error and it says error is in this bit of code

```
rotation.z = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 180);
            spawnPosition.y += UnityEngine.Random.Range(minY, maxY);
            spawnPosition.x = UnityEngine.Random.Range(-levelWidth, levelWidth);
    ERROR IS HERE >>>Instantiate(platformPrefab, spawnPosition, rotation);
```

Comment: Have you tried declaring `rotation` to be a `Quaternion` instead of a `Vector3`?  Rotations are described by quaternions instead of Euler angles.  See [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/QuaternionAndEulerRotationsInUnity.html)

Comment: this solved my problem,thanks! But my platforms dont rotate for some reason they are all facing the same direction.(sorry for bad english)

Comment: sorry im very new at this i cant figure out how to select your comment as the best answer

Comment: Comments are not answers.  I copied the comment into an answer if you want to select it

Comment: @Yigit0504 please [see here for more information about accepting answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Quaternion.Euler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Euler.html) replacing the last line with

```
Instantiate(platformPrefab, spawnPosition, Quaternion.Euler(rotation ));
```

Comment: This answer would be the correcter one since simply making the type of `rotation` a `Quaternion` as suggested would lead to strange behavior since you don't simply set the `z` component of a `Quaternion` unless you know exactly what you are doing (which can not be the case if you try to set it to something between 0 and 180 ^^)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried declaring rotation to be a Quaternion instead of a Vector3? Rotations are described by quaternions instead of Euler angles.

See [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/QuaternionAndEulerRotationsInUnity.html)

Comment: Yes but this is not the full answer because in this case you definitely wouldn't set the `z` value "manually" ...

Comment: it's still returning the same error. using `Quaternion.Euler` will work.